# angular-tree-component | get Path

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, angular5

Does anyone know how i can get the full Path, when I am clicking on a Node.
 I have seen a path option in the API, but I don't know exactly how to use it with the click event.

```
options: ITreeOptions = {
 actionMapping: {
  mouse: {
    dblClick: (tree, node, $event) => {

    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what format you need you can build out the lineage/path yourself

```
options: ITreeOptions = {
    actionMapping: {
        mouse: {
            dblClick: (tree, node, $event) => {
                const lineage = [];
                // add clicked node as first item
                lineage.push(node.data);

                // grab parent of clicked node
                let parent = node.parent;

                // loop through parents until the root of the tree is reached
                while(parent !== null){
                    lineage.push(parent.data);
                    parent = parent.parent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for!  lol If this was my question I would've given it a check mark!  Thanks!